# ¿Como puedo pasar datos de un formulario a otro en tiempo real C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que pasa es que tengo que escribir en un formulario y al mismo tiempo en el form2 pasar lo que estoy escribiendo.

Comment: podrias mirar [ask]? cual es el problema particular que tuviste tratando de hacer esto? son dos objetos a los cuales se les pueden pasar variables como a cualquier otro. intentaste algo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo como esto

> Función en `form2`, supongamos que este tiene un `label` llamado `lbl_1`

```
public void EditarLabel(string _ValorDelForm1)
 {
   lbl_1.text = _ValorDelForm1;
 }
```

> Codigo del `form1`, supongamos que este tiene un `textbox` llamado `txt_1`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        //Obtenemos control del form2, atento que esto se hace a nivel clase.
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         //Mostramos el form2.
         frm2.Show();
       }

        private void txt_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Ejecutamos la funcion del form2 llamandolo desde el control que tuvimos
           frm2.EditarLabel(txt_1.text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Martín , podrías haber esperado a que el usuario aporte la mas mínima prueba de que ha hecho algo de verdad. Tal cual esta la pregunta parece que solo quiere que la gente le haga los deberes. ¿No crees?

Comment: Ahora que lo dices la verdad si, me parece lo que tu dices. ¿Lo correcto seria borrar la respuesta?.

Comment: Yo personalmente creo que no, tu respuesta parece buena y al final este sitio es como una gran biblioteca de código.Seguro que le sera útil a futuros usuarios! :)

Answer (score -3):

Esto es bastante fácil usando Javascript y más todavía con JQuery.

Suponiendo que quieres pasar el dato de input1 a input2 haríamos lo siguiente.

1. Recupera el valor del input1 (Suponemos que su id

```js
var value1 = document.getElementById("wpforms-3222-field_0").value
```

2. Inyectamos el valor en input2

```js
document.getElementById("input2").value = value1;
```

Esto con Jquery es más simple

```js
$("#input2").val($("#input1").val())
```

Además si quieres que se actualice por cada carácter que introduzcas tendrás que usar el evento `keyup` o `keydown` del `#input1`.

Saludos!

Comment: Jorge, te has dado cuenta que la pregunta del usuario es de Winforms y específicamente de C#?